# What is the maximum size for a animated gif?

Tags: support

I think I tried a couple of times to post an animated gif and sometime the file did not appear in the question.

Then I ask:

What is the maximum size for this type of file?

Comment: The maximum file size is 2 MB for all types of images if you use the built in image uploader. It should warn you that the image was too large though, not just fail to disappear.

Comment: When I make a gif that is over 2MB, I just go to imgur directly and upload it, then link to the file in the post - like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/interstellar-image-effects/114155#114155) where I included a 45MB gif.

Comment: @JasonB Really this was a comment useful. I needed a lot to know that.